# property bindings in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am having tough time in understanding property bindings in angular 6.

I am confused about when I should us **[property]="something"** and when **property="something"**

```
<div
    class="row"
    style="margin-top: 10px;" 
    *ngFor="let ingredientControl of recipeEditForm.get('ingredients').controls;let i=index"
    [formGroupName]="i">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            formControlName="name"
            >
    </div>
</div>
```

In my code above, why is formGroupName enclosed in [] and why formControl isn't.

What will happen if I swap the [] on them ? Ofcourse it throws error, by why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here: [Remember the brackets](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets)

> The brackets tell Angular to evaluate the template expression. If you
>   omit the brackets, Angular treats the string as a constant and
>   initializes the target property with that string. It does not evaluate
>   the string!

Assuming **i** ranges from 0 to 2, including brackets, like this...

```
<div [formGroupName]="i">
```

...will produce...

```
<div formGroupName="0">
<div formGroupName="1">
<div formGroupName="2">
```

...while excluding brackets, like this...

```
<div formGroupName="i">
```

...will produce...

```
<div formGroupName="i">
<div formGroupName="i">
<div formGroupName="i">
```

...which is probably not what you want.

In the case of **formControlName**, if you added square brackets, like this...

```
<input [formControlName]="name">
```

...angular will attempt to evaluate **name** and assign the result to **formControlName**. Maybe **name** exists as a component property?

Without the square brackets, **formControlName** will just be assigned the literal value **'name'**.

Comment: thank you very much. It's crystal clear to me now. :-)